# How to stop the execution of below javascript code when taking prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, prompt

This is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    $("div").append("I Want to Display this before user enter input in Prompt <br>")
    setTimeout(function() {
        input = prompt("test");
        //PUT more code here
    });
    $("div").append("I Want to Display this after user enter input in Prompt")

}
```

Here is the fiddle:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa5ownd8/8/)

This is what I want

> I Want to Display this before user enter input in Prompt
>
> Now Take Input
>
> I Want to Display this after user enter input in Prompt
>
> I Want to Display this before user enter input in Prompt
>
> Now Take Input
>
> I Want to Display this after user enter input in Prompt

I want to take input from the user in this way. If not by prompt, then any other way?

Comment: Just put the lower `append` at the bottom of the `setTimeout` function

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I failed to explain my problem properly. Please see the updated code

Comment: @sdad so when do you expect to stop the prompt? I see there are two prompts you are looking for in your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep that `append` in the `div` inside the `setTimeout()` function and you can also check for `input` value is `null` or not for user input. Besides this, use `setInterval()` to keep showing the prompt as in your updated question so that when the user press `cancel` the prompt is closed forever.

```js
$("div").append("I Want to Display this before user enter input in Prompt <br>")
var promptLoop = setInterval(function(){
  var input = prompt("test");
  if(input !== null && input.trim() !== ''){
    $("div").append("<br/>I Want to Display this after user enter input in Prompt. User input is " + input)
  } else {
    clearInterval(promptLoop);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think I failed to explain my problem properly. Please see the updated code

Comment: @sdad so when do you expect to stop the prompt? I see there are two prompts you are looking for in your updated question.

Comment: Just like the input works in tubro C++ compiler. I want the prompt to work like that. 

First display a text > Take Input > Stop prompt > Display later text > Start next loop > First display a text > Take Input > Stop Prompt > Display later text > Stop the program.

Comment: Use `while` loop in that code to make it continuous loop

Comment: While loop will not solve the problem. See the expected output in the question. Can you update your fiddle please?

Comment: @sdad I have updated the above code. Check that. It should be what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated code.

https://jsfiddle.net/sa5ownd8/7/

added the `append` code just after the `prompt` function.

Comment: I think I failed to explain my problem properly. Please see the updated code

Comment: @sdad so when do you expect to stop the prompt? I see there are two prompts you are looking for in your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `setTimout` function is asynchronous which means that the block of code that is inside of it is not executed right away but instead is put into an `event queue` which waits till all the rest of the code in the same scope is executed and only then it is executed.

If you want to execute some code only after the `setTimeout`'s delay has passed, then you need to put all of that code inside of the `setTimeout`.

```js
$("div").append("I Want to Display this before user enter input in Prompt <br>")
setTimeout(function() {
    const input = prompt("test");
    //PUT more code here

    $("div").append("I Want to Display this after user enter input in Prompt")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think I failed to explain my problem properly. Please see the updated code

Comment: @sdad so when do you expect to stop the prompt? I see there are two prompts you are looking for in your updated question.